# Ошибка в TortoiseSVN при коммите и в создании версий контроля в UE 5.3

Tags: svn, unreal-engine-5, unreal-engine, tortoise-svn

Хотим сделать папку, куда можно будет сохранять все изменения. Папка хранится на яндекс.диске: [image: 1]
Но при коммите, либо при добавлении версии контроля в анриле енджин, у меня вылезает ошибка, которую прикрепил. У друга все нормально, хотя делали все-тоже самое.
Тут я пытаюсь добавить контроль версий
[image: 2]

Вот логи
[image: 3]

А это, я пытаюсь создать коммит в папке
[image: 4]